# How to find data length and index length of innodb tables in mysql 5.6 if innodb per file is not enabled

Tags: mysql, innodb, information-schema

In mysql 5.6, We have innodb per file is disabled. I just want to know size of tables data and index . Please let me know how to get accurate data.

Comment: can you use SQL to determine the size? https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/determining-the-size-of-mysql-databases-and-tables#:~:text=To%20determine%20the%20sizes%20of%20all%20of%20your%20databases%2C%20at,(MB)%22%20FROM%20information_schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you get data length and index length if innodb_file_per_table is enabled:

```
SELECT data_length, index_length
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE ENGINE='InnoDB';
```

Or if you want the total:

```
SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) AS total
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE ENGINE='InnoDB';
```

The data length and index length are not different if you enable/disable innodb_file_per_table.

What is counted differently is the `data_free`. If you have disabled innodb_file_per_table, the data_free of the whole tablespace will be reported for each row in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. So you should not `SUM()` the data_free, because that will give you a misleading result. It will count the same data_free many times, equal to the number of InnoDB tables in the tablespace.

Comment: I used same commands but getting mis match of 50 GBs. total data size and index size are 170 GB and ibdata1 is of 224 GB

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the `data_free`. It can also include the undo segment and change buffer, because ibdata1 contains stuff not included in tables.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I want to get all details which is consuming my space. Please note: Data free I'm considering here. Still have some mis match. So we have any specific way to check space consumed by ibdata1 stuff (meta data, change buffer, table space, undo logs ).

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that with SQL queries. There exists a third-party tool that can examine the pages of a MySQL database in detail: https://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/03/a-quick-introduction-to-innodb-ruby/

Comment: Thanks Bill. I'll look further for  these 3rd party tools

Answer (score 0):

`SHOW TABLE STATUS` provides that info for the current db.  Note that `Data_free` will refer to `ibdata1`, not the table.